# Replace All Format Chars Inside Quotation Marks

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have a Regular Expression that should replace all format characters (`\t, \r\, \n, \v, whitespace`) with `~` characters IF these format characters occur between two quotation marks (`"`).

My code is not producing the desired result, instead its replacing the first quotation mark with `~` then leaving the rest. **What's wrong with my Regular Expression and how I can make it achieve my desired result?**

For the following string:   `name      "Right \r\nCurb"`
The result should be:       `name      "Right~~~Curb"`
But my code is producing: `name      ~Right \r\nCurb"`

My code:

```
const string delimeters = "(\"*[\\t\\r\\n\\v\\b\\s]\")";
var openBrkRgx = new Regex(delimeters);
line = openBrkRgx.Replace(line, "~");
```

Comment: Why are you double-escaping the items in the character class?

Comment: @AmalMurali In C# I thought I must do this because these format chars are inside 2 quotation groups (nested twice). Maybe I dont need to though? Edit: Just checked, yeah C# gives a compile error with 1 escape character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern `[\t\r\n\v\s](?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`
and replace with `~`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qT6mB4)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different ways of doing this.

- (`1.`) *Negative Lookahead*

  ```
  Regex.Replace(input, @"\s(?!(([^""]*""){2})*[^""]*$)", "~");
  ```

  **Note**: In NET, `\s` itself matches any *Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line*

  [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qH8iY3)
- (`2.`) Matching the quotes, then do your replacements: (*Suggested*..)

  ```
  Regex.Replace(input, @"""[^""]+""", 
                m => m.Value.Replace(' ',  '~')
                            .Replace("\t", "~")
                            .Replace("\r", "~")
                            .Replace("\n", "~")
                );
  ```

  [**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/GPY0F5)